# Many classes use an object, but having different views of it

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, readonly

Sorry for the title, I couldn't think of a more self-descriptive one.

In the stand-alone application I'm developing (it's a university assignment) I'm facing this problem:
I've got my entities (or Model objects or Business object etc) which are nothing more than POJOs.

Naturally there are (will be) many classes that uses them, but some of these classes should not be allowed to modify their value (e.g. using their setters); we can say that I need to pass an object to different classes with different permissions: read-only to some classes, read-write to others that are allowed to modify the state of the object.

An example would be a GUI window that only displays information about the object: I would like to make sure that this class is totally unaware of how modify the state of the object.

I read a lot of topics with some related problems (read-only interfaces, read-only implementation, defensive copies, etc...) but I did not find anything suitable for my case.

Let's say I would like to **grant access to the setter methods of an object only to specific classes**, but I can't find a way to achieve this.

I initially thought that interfaces would be fine (eg `ReadOnlyObject` with getters and `WriteOnlyObject` with setters and `Object` implementing both of them) but the problem is that `WriteOnlyObject` interface would be easily reachable by any class that uses `ReadOnlyObject`.
Beside that, I'm not convinced that writing interfaces with only getters or setters is a good practice.

Please help! @_@

Comment: Your business objects could implement interfaces which each provide a subset of getter methods to access the data of the business object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOP is all about adhering to contracts. If a method's contract states that it will not modify an object, it should not do so even if it can -- and if it does, that's a bug. There's nothing wrong with passing around business objects directly to the GUI.

Of course, you should design classes to be immutable whenever possible, but most business objects are not immutable and trying to work around this leads to clunky solutions. If you're still worried about exposing setters, the best solution would be to create an immutable transfer object that contains copies of the original values.

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering about that and I came up to this same conclusion (actually, both the solutions you suggested, in reverse order).

But I do really think that doesn't make almost any sense to make interfaces for simple POJOs with only getters and setters and any class that uses a model object has the responsability over it.
Thanks casablanca :)

Answer (score 1):

For a given pojo, call it "Customer", you should create two interfaces.  Create an interface named ICustomerRO that has only getter methods.  Create an interface named ICustomer that extends ICustomerRO and adds the setter methods.  Finally, create your pojo with fully functional getter and setter methods and which implements ICustomer.

Of course, you can use whatever naming convention you'd like.

In your code, wherever you create a method that should have read-only access to the pojo, be sure to type the argument as ICustomerRO.  When you have a method that should have read-write access to the pojo, type the argument as ICustomer.  In either case, pass in a Customer object.  This lets you control who has access to which methods and exploits the java editor's ability to show only the methods that are appropriate for the context of use.

Answer (score 0):

Make your models interfaces and hand out read-only impls - ie ones that throw UnsupportedOperationException in the setters, similar to what `Collections.unmodifiableXXX()` does - to those processes that have read-only permissions.

The trick is know which callers have what permissions. Don't let the pojo know/decide. Use some kind of factory class that can register who is who and who gets what kind of copy.